# Toric surfaces glued from affine plane $\mathbb{A}^2$'s

Tags: algebraic-geometry, fiber-bundles

I'm figuring out toric surfaces corresponding to the following six toric fans in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
[image]

I found that the first one corresponds to the affine plane $\mathbb{A}^2$,
and the second one corresponds to the blown up surface $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1)$.

But I couldn't find a nice description of the other four surfaces.
Do they also have a good name or some nice understanding?